# WebServers cannot connect to app server ELB - AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I have a simple deployment with some webservers connected to an `AWS ELB`. This `ELB` in-turn has some application servers behind it.

The webservers are unable to connect to the application server ELB. The `httpd` error log is full of:

```
[Thu Dec 22 15:28:05.897273 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 10188] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 54.254.179.37:80 (elblinkhere) failed
[Thu Dec 22 15:28:05.897348 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 10188] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (elblinkhere) for 60s
[Thu Dec 22 15:28:05.897361 2016] [proxy_http:error] [pid 10188] [client 10.0.0.54:13789] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: elblinkhere
```

I have tried to check if this is an `SELinux` issue but that does not seem so.
I have also read a large number of threads on the internet about this and not come across any solutions.

My question(s):
1. What other methods can I use to resolve this?
2. How do I resolve this?

Comment: is port 80 is open in your application server ? you can check it using the security group of your app-server.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure your ELB as external and also enabled necessary port for ELB's security group?

Comment: ELB is configured as external. Ports 80 and 8009 are configured for access by the web servers.

Comment: I can reach the ip via port 80. ( http://54.254.179.37/ shows apache test page ). So it seems that the problem is with your webservers' outbound access. Are these webservers also in AWS? Also can you give some infromation about your VPC setup?

Comment: Yes. These webservers are also on AWS. The inbound for the ELB is set to receive requests from the webserver security group over 80 & 8009 (for AJP)

Comment: And what about the VPC and subnets? Are the web servers in public subnet? Do they have outbound policy in their security-group? Trying to figure out the architecture.

Comment: Yes. The webservers and appservers are in the same VPC. The webservers are in a public subnet and the application servers are supposed to be in the private subnet.

Comment: Can you trace the ELB from your webservers and paste the output?

Comment: All packets are lost.

Comment: Do your webservers have public ip or elastic ip? If not, please attach EIP one of them and try please.

Comment: That was the problem. The webservers did not have a public IP and were not able to access the internet. These servers were trying to reference the public DNS of the external-facing application load balancer. No internet, DNS never functioned. Hence the problem. Do you mind writing your last comment (in more detail) as the answer. I will mark it correct?

Comment: Your web servers should have either public ip or elastic ip, in order to make them reach internet so they can reach the ELB.

Comment: Yes. I converted the external facing ELB to an internal one. Initial tests seem to have rectified the problem